# Flutter FutureBuilder - how to return component even if data is null?

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I have an odd problem. I am invoking a method to get a device locale.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: platform.invokeMethod('locale'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);
        if (snapshot.error is MissingPluginException) {
          return App(
            locale: "is",
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          return App(
            locale: snapshot.data,
          );
        } else {
          return App(locale: "is");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But I want a default value to be "is" if for example there is not internet connection. However when I test it, the screen is just blank. It works when there is internet connection and return the App component with a locale. But it wont if it's off.

I also tried:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: platform.invokeMethod('locale'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);
        if (snapshot.error is MissingPluginException) {
          return App(
            locale: "is",
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          return App(
            locale: snapshot.data,
          );
        }
        return App(locale: "is");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But it won't work.

Comment: what are the values of `snapshot.data` and `snapshot.error` that is printed?

Comment: snapshot.data is either null or a string and snapshot.error is null if snapshot.data is not null or it is an Object.